# How to get a value from an executeUpdate OR update in java?

Tags: java, postgresql, executequery, sql-returning

Im trying to get some returning data from an postgresql update. The "update" works well in the DB script, but in java I'm having some issues: the code stucks while executing the query.

I'm trying with "PreparedStatament ps", "ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery" and "if(rs.next)" to get the data from the "returning" in the query, but it appears that the code didnt get in there, because it stuck exactly in the "ps.executeQuery".

Here's more or less what I'm trying to do:

```
String cVal="";
ps=myConn.prepareStatement("UPDATE someTable SET aValue=? WHERE bValue=? 
returning Cvalue");
ps.setInt(1,"aNewValue");
ps.setInt(2,"aID");
rs=ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()){
  cVal=rs.GetString("Cvalue");
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
```

I'm trying to set the values of "RETURNING" to some variables. There are 4 results that I want to set.

Comment: use `executeUpdate()`; for updates, inserts and deletes, instead of `executeQuery()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to update, in case of PreparedStatement, you have to use executeUpdate() method.

To know more details about methods in Statement and PreparedStatment, check below the

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--

You can refer below an example.
https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-update-a-record/

Comment: I do know that executeUpdate returns an 1 or a 0, but how can I get the values from the returning? is there any kind of "rs.get..." only in the executeUpdate??

Comment: You will get the number of affected rows using update query.

Answer (score -1):

First execute the update statement with `ps.executeUpdate ()`, which returns the integer `0` or `1`. The value indicates whether the update statement has executed or not. After that, execute the select query to get the updated data.

Comment: Please consider adding punctuation to your answer, for readability's sake.